# WPF Prism, Set several dependency properties of a View (UserControl) from inside Shell

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, prism

In *Prism* each `View` is a `UserControl` and i have a `View` include a `dependency property` like this (inside `MyView.xaml.cs`):

```
public int WidgetCornerRadius
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(WidgetCornerRadiusProperty); }
    set { SetValue(WidgetCornerRadiusProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CornerRadius",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(MyView),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(7));
```

I show the `MyView.xaml` in the following `Region` (in `Shell.xaml`):

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="TargetRegion"/>
```

Now my question is how can i fill the `CornerRadius` `dependency property` of the View from inside `Shell`? Am i need register a new `RegionAdapter`? May you show me how?

I want something like this:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="TargetRegion"
                CornerRadius="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing this CornerRadius to your view, can you not just look from the view for relative source to find that property? it should be much easier this way. Lets say you have a border which is depended on it, all you'll have to do is something like this

```
 <Border CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type HereComesyourType}}, Path=CornerRadius}"/>
```